# The use of IN operator in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, operator-keyword

I have a database with products, associated with brands and models of vehicles.

I have the reference of the product and the model in which that product can operate. In the web, I have a select of models, I select one model and the query is of the type:

```
SELECT * FROM {tables - relationships among tables } WHERE [...] model = 125
```

Now if in the select field I allow for multiple checkings, I would have something like

```
SELECT * FROM {tables - relationships among tables } WHERE [...] model IN (125, 126, 127)
```

This Ok. It will return back products which can be applied to models 125 or 126 or 127. A product can be used in 125 and 126, other product can only be used for 127, etc.

Now if I want products that ONLY can be used in all three models selected, i.e., 125 and 126 and 127, I am confussed, not sure of how could I do it, because the IN operator will return the same that in the second example.

Is there some GROUP BY action to have into account?

Comment: `GROUP BY {product} HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model) = 3` (if `model` is necessarily distinct, you can omit that keyword to save on the additional sorting operation).

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems very logical now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by user eggyal (see commentaries above), I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM {tables - relationships among tables } WHERE [...] model IN (125, 126, 127) GROUP BY {product} HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model) = 3
```

with success.